# Object expected Microsoft JScript runtime error 800A138F when viewing diffs inside of TortoiseSVN update log

Tags: svn, diff, tortoise-svn, runtime-error

1. After I get an update, I double click a JavaScript file in my update log and get the following error message:

   [image: Microsoft JScript runtime error - object expected - Code 800A138F]

   I've tried clearing everything inside of Settings -> Saved Data but I still get errors. I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.9.5. I had this issue in older versions of TortoiseSVN as well. How do I resolve this error?
2. If I click other non-JavaScript files that have been "Updated" I would like to see a diff of those changes compared to the previous revision. I've tried going to Settings -> General -> Dialogs 1 and checking the "Can double-click log list to compare with previous revision" checkbox, but it simply opens up the files in an appropriate editor and doesn't do a diff on them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To successfully fix the problem, I ran the sfc command at the command prompt:

```
sfc /scannow
```